# Como agrupar una lista de elementos cuando padres e hijos sean iguales?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

estoy batallando para agrupar los elementos de una lista, siempre y cuando sus elementos padre y sus hijos sean iguales de caso contrario no se haga.

La salida debe ser de esta Manera

```
  Padre:
    Grupo: 148096
    Cantidad: 2
    ProductoID: 87
    Hijo:
    MesaProdmodDetalleLista 
                           -ModificadorID 13,
                           -Cantidad: 2
 Padre:
    Grupo: 148096
    Producto:83
    Cantidad:2
    Hijo
    MesaProdmodDetalleLista : 0
    ---------------------------------------------
  Padre:
    Grupo: 148098
    Cantidad: 1
    ProductoID: 87
    Hijo
    MesaProdmodDetalleLista 
                           -ModificadorID 12
                           -Cantidad: 1
  Padre
    Grupo: 148098
    ProductoID: 83
    Cantidad: 1
    Hijo
    MesaProdmodDetalleLista: 0
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
static List<jmpm_mesaprodmod> llena() {

    List<jmpm_mesaprodmod> datos = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmod>();

    jmpm_mesaprodmod jmpm_mesaprodmod1 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod() {
        ID = 355,
        Cantidad = 1,
        Comentario = null,
        JMPM_Comensal = 1,
        JMPM_Grupo = 148096,
        JMPM_MesaID = 13834,
        JMPM_ProductoID = 83,
        JMPM_PromocionID = 1,
        JMPM_PromocionPrecio = 39,
        JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmod jmpm_mesaprodmod2 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod()
    {
        ID = 356,
        Cantidad = 1,
        Comentario = null,
        JMPM_Comensal = 1,
        JMPM_Grupo = 148096,
        JMPM_MesaID = 13834,
        JMPM_ProductoID = 87,
        JMPM_PromocionID = 1,
        JMPM_PromocionPrecio = 39,
        JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle detalle = new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle() {
        ID = 575,
        JMPMD_Cantidad = 1,
        JMPMD_MesaProdModID = 356,
        JMPMD_ModificadorID=13,
        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 0
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmod2.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Add(detalle);


    jmpm_mesaprodmod jmpm_mesaprodmod3 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod()
    {
        ID = 357,
        Cantidad = 1,
        Comentario = null,
        JMPM_Comensal = 1,
        JMPM_Grupo = 148097,
        JMPM_MesaID = 13834,
        JMPM_ProductoID = 83,
        JMPM_PromocionID = 1,
        JMPM_PromocionPrecio = 39,
        JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmod jmpm_mesaprodmod4 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod()
    {
        ID = 358,
        Cantidad = 1,
        Comentario = null,
        JMPM_Comensal = 1,
        JMPM_Grupo = 148097,
        JMPM_MesaID = 13834,
        JMPM_ProductoID = 87,
        JMPM_PromocionID = 1,
        JMPM_PromocionPrecio = 39,
        JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle detalle4 = new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle()
    {
        ID = 576,
        JMPMD_Cantidad = 1,
        JMPMD_MesaProdModID = 358,
        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 13,
        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 0
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmod4.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Add(detalle4);


    jmpm_mesaprodmod jmpm_mesaprodmod5 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod()
    {
        ID = 359,
        Cantidad = 1,
        Comentario = null,
        JMPM_Comensal = 1,
        JMPM_Grupo = 148098,
        JMPM_MesaID = 13834,
        JMPM_ProductoID = 83,
        JMPM_PromocionID = 1,
        JMPM_PromocionPrecio = 39,
        JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmod jmpm_mesaprodmod6 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod()
    {
        ID = 360,
        Comentario = null,
        JMPM_Comensal = 1,
        JMPM_Grupo = 148098,
        JMPM_MesaID = 13834,
        JMPM_ProductoID = 87,
        JMPM_PromocionID = 1,
        JMPM_PromocionPrecio = 39,
        JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle detalle6 = new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle()
    {
        ID = 576,
        JMPMD_Cantidad = 1,
        JMPMD_MesaProdModID = 360,
        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 12,
        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 0
    };

    jmpm_mesaprodmod6.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Add(detalle6);


    datos.Add(jmpm_mesaprodmod1);
    datos.Add(jmpm_mesaprodmod2);
    datos.Add(jmpm_mesaprodmod3);
    datos.Add(jmpm_mesaprodmod4);
    datos.Add(jmpm_mesaprodmod5);
    datos.Add(jmpm_mesaprodmod6);

    return datos;

}


Clases
public class jmpm_mesaprodmod 
    {
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public int JMPM_ID { get; set; }
        public int JMPM_MesaID { get; set; }
        public int JMPM_UsuarioID { get; set; }
        public int JMPM_ProductoID { get; set; }
        public float JMPM_ProductoPrecio { get; set; }
        public DateTime JMPM_Fecha { get; set; }
        public int? JMPM_PromocionID { get; set; }
        public float? JMPM_PromocionPrecio { get; set; }
        public int JMPM_Grupo { get; set; }
        public int? JMPM_Comensal { get; set; }
        
        public List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle> JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista { get; set; }
        
        public string Comentario { get; set; }
        
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.JMPM_ID;
            }

            set
            {
                this.JMPM_ID = value;
            }
        }
        
        public bool AutoNumeric
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle 
    {
        public int JMPMD_ID { get; set; }
        public int JMPMD_MesaProdModID { get; set; }
        public int JMPMD_ModificadorID { get; set; }
        public float JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio { get; set; }
        public int JMPMD_Cantidad { get; set; }
        
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.JMPMD_ID;
            }
            set
            {
                this.JMPMD_ID = value;
            }
        }
        
        public bool AutoNumeric
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

y el codigo que implemente:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           

            var individuales = llena();
            List<float> precios = individuales.Select(p => (p.JMPM_PromocionPrecio ?? 0)).Distinct().ToList();

            var groupedCustomerList = individuales.GroupBy(u => u.JMPM_ProductoID)
                                     .Select(grp => new { ProductoID = grp.Key, CustomerList = grp.ToList() })
                                     .ToList();

            foreach (float precio in precios)
            {

                List<int> ids = individuales.Where(p => p.JMPM_PromocionPrecio == precio).Select(p => p.JMPM_Grupo).Distinct().ToList();

                List<jmpm_mesaprodmod> datos = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmod>();

                if (ids != null && ids.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var GrupoID in ids)
                    {
                        var individualGrupos = individuales.Where(d => d.JMPM_Grupo == GrupoID).ToList();

                        foreach (var individual in individualGrupos)
                        {
                            jmpm_mesaprodmod jmpm_mesaprodmod = new jmpm_mesaprodmod();
                            var producto = datos.Where(x => x.JMPM_ProductoID == individual.JMPM_ProductoID).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (producto == null)
                            {
                                jmpm_mesaprodmod = individual;
                                if (individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista != null && individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Any())
                                {
                                    jmpm_mesaprodmod.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista;
                                }
                                datos.Add(jmpm_mesaprodmod);
                            }
                            else {

                                var existente = datos.Where(x => x.JMPM_ProductoID == producto.JMPM_ProductoID).FirstOrDefault();
                                if (existente.JMPM_Grupo != individual.JMPM_Grupo)
                                {
                                    bool ProductoIgual = false;
                                    bool ModificadorIgual = false;

                                    if (existente.JMPM_ProductoID == individual.JMPM_ProductoID)
                                        ProductoIgual = true;

                                    if (individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Any())
                                    {
                                        foreach (var item in individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista)
                                        {
                                            foreach (var existe in existente.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista)
                                            {
                                                if (item.JMPMD_ModificadorID == existe.JMPMD_ModificadorID)
                                                {
                                                    ModificadorIgual = true;
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    ModificadorIgual = false;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        //true si es diferente grupo y no tiene una variante
                                        ModificadorIgual = false;
                                    }
                                    // 97  buscar al grupo y determinar si tiene modificador 

                                    
                                    

                                    if (ProductoIgual && ModificadorIgual)
                                    {
                                        int promocionid = 0;

                                        int grupoID = individual.JMPM_Grupo;

                                        if (existente.JMPM_ProductoID == individual.JMPM_ProductoID) {

                                            existente.Cantidad += individual.Cantidad;

                                            if (individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Any())
                                            {

                                                int Cantidad = individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Sum(d =>d.JMPMD_Cantidad);
                                                
                                                existente.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.ForEach(f => f.JMPMD_Cantidad += Cantidad);
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        jmpm_mesaprodmod = individual;

                                        if (individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista != null && individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Any())
                                        {
                                            jmpm_mesaprodmod.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = individual.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista;
                                        }

                                        datos.Add(jmpm_mesaprodmod);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Esta es la salida, en teoria es sumar los objetos siempre y cuando sus hijos sean iguales.
que seria la salia que les mostre, una lista unicamente con 4 objetos

Gracias:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrego código de agrupación.

La idea es agrupar los objetos por `JMPM_ProductoID` y `JMPMD_ModificadorID`. Con esa agrupación todos los objetos tendrán esas dos cosas en común.

Para eso se filtran solo los objetos que tengan detalle y se ignoran los demás.

Luego hay que elegir uno de esos objetos, en este caso el primero y al detalle de este objeto agregar la suma de todas las cantidades de los detalles de los objetos de este grupo.

Al finalizar se tiene una colección que tiene un solo objeto por `JMPM_ProductoID` y `JMPMD_ModificadorID`.

Después se agrega a la colección los objetos que no se habían incluido por no tener detalle.

```
var data = llena();

// crear lista con objetos que tienen detalles
var registroConDetalle = data.FindAll(d =>d.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Count > 0);

// crear grupos por JMPMD_ModificadorID y JMPM_ProductoID
var grupo = registroConDetalle.GroupBy(g =>new {
  g.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.First().JMPMD_ModificadorID,
  g.JMPM_ProductoID
});

// de la nueva colección agrupada seleccionar el primer objeto
//y guardar en su detalle la suma de JMPMD_Cantidad

var objetosFusionados = grupo.Select(g =>{

  var objeto = g.First(); // elegir el primer objeto

  // guardar en su detalle la suma de JMPMD_Cantidad de este grupo
  objeto.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.First().JMPMD_Cantidad = g.Sum(e =>e.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Sum(de =>de.JMPMD_Cantidad));

  return objeto;

}).ToList();

// de la colección original recuperar los objetos que no se incluyeron
// por no tener detalle y que coinciden con el id de los objetos fusionados
var objetosNoIncluidos = data.Where(d =>objetosFusionados.Select(d1 =>d1.JMPM_Grupo).Contains(d.JMPM_Grupo) && d.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Count == 0).ToList();

// agregar los objetos no incluidos
objetosFusionados.AddRange(objetosNoIncluidos);

// agrupar para impresión y actualizar totales
var resultado = objetosFusionados.GroupBy(r =>new {
  r.JMPM_Grupo
}).Select(o =>{

  var total = o.Sum(d =>d.Cantidad);
  o.ToList().ForEach(e =>e.Cantidad = total);

  return o;
}).ToList();


// impresión de resultados
resultado.ForEach(re =>{

  re.ToList().ForEach(r =>{

    Console.WriteLine("Padre:");
    Console.WriteLine("Grupo: " + r.JMPM_Grupo);
    Console.WriteLine("Cantidad: " + r.Cantidad);
    Console.WriteLine("ProductoId: " + r.JMPM_ProductoID);
    Console.WriteLine("Hijo: ");
    Console.WriteLine("MesaProdmodDetalleLista: " + (r.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Count == 0 ? "0": ""));

    if (r.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Count != 0) {
      Console.WriteLine("\t-ModificadorID: " + (r.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Count == 0 ? "": r.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.FirstOrDefault() ? .JMPMD_ModificadorID.ToString()));

      Console.WriteLine("\t-Cantidad: " + (r.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Count == 0 ? "": r.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.FirstOrDefault() ? .JMPMD_Cantidad.ToString()));
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
  });

  Console.WriteLine("____________________________");

});
```

Salida:

```
Padre:
Grupo: 148096
Cantidad: 2
ProductoId: 87
Hijo: 
MesaProdmodDetalleLista: 
        -ModificadorID: 13
        -Cantidad: 2

Padre:
Grupo: 148096
Cantidad: 2
ProductoId: 83
Hijo: 
MesaProdmodDetalleLista: 0

____________________________
Padre:
Grupo: 148098
Cantidad: 1
ProductoId: 87
Hijo: 
MesaProdmodDetalleLista: 
        -ModificadorID: 12
        -Cantidad: 1

Padre:
Grupo: 148098
Cantidad: 1
ProductoId: 83
Hijo: 
MesaProdmodDetalleLista: 0
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero el 148097 son las entidades que tomo y se los sumo a los demas objetos por eso es que en este ejemplo no debe de tomarse

Comment: las entidades con el grupo 148097 se fueron sumando con el de 148096, es decir por tener productoid y modificadorid similares

Comment: Ok. Y el 148098 por qué tiene ModificadorID = 13 cuando en los datos es 12?

Comment: ah, porque es un distinto modificador, por eso ya no se tomaria en cuenta y seria un grupoo aparte, en cambio el grupo 148097 y 148096 tienen tanto productoId y modificadorId Similares por ende se agruparian. y en el ejemplo el grupo 148097 pudo haber permanecido o el grupo 148096, pero uno basicamente no existiria

Comment: Me refiero a que el 148098 en los datos tiene un modificadorID = 12 pero en el ejemplo es 13, por qué se incrementa?

Comment: Tuve un error en las id de modificadores, en toda la lista hay dos ModificadorID = 13 y Uno ModificadorID = 12, los ModificadorID no se incrementan (Edite la pregunte) una disculpa

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.